# spark join generate detected cartesian product exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframe with next schemas:

1st

- s: string (nullable = true)
- r: string (nullable = true)
- Map: string (nullable = true)
- r1: string (nullable = true)
- c1: string (nullable = true)
- s2: string (nullable = true)
- s3: string (nullable = true)
- N: string (nullable = true)

2nd

- k: string (nullable = true)
- k1: string (nullable = true)
- M: string (nullable = true)
- M1: string (nullable = true)
- Map: string (nullable = true)

When I want to join them I've got "**Detected cartesian product for INNER join between logical plans" exception**".

I have tried several joins:

```
val df = df1.join(df2, "Map")

val df = df1.join(df2, df1("Map") === df2("Map") )
```

etc. but I've got exception every time. What am I missing?

Comment: Resolved: 1 of dataframes already have wrong union

Comment: what do you mean with "wrong union"? Could you show how you exactly resolved this?

Comment: Sorry for delay :) As I remember correctly I was trying to rejoin dataframes, so basically I was trying to do 2  joins when I need just left join.